# Oracle apex does not open

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have installed Oracle apex 20.1.
When I want to open admin page, browser get me this error: This sit can't be reached.
I use this address: localhost:8080/apex
Apex version: 20.1
Oracle database version: 19c
OS: Windows server 2016
The database is mount and open
port 8080 has been allowed
So what should I do?

Comment: What are you using for your application tier? Oracle Webtier, Apache Tomcat, or ORDS Standalone? Are they running on port 8080? Check the logs wherever you have ORDS deployed and make sure it started up successfully.

Comment: I have installed just apex like always. At first I install apex then check that is apex work correctly then I install ORDS. So I don't know what is default server for oracle apex

Answer (score 0):

we use this, which I think is the default: localhost:8080/ords